# Desktop tab blank under System Preferences → Desktop & Screen Saver

Tags: mojave, preferences

My desktop tab under Desktop & Screen Saver is showing up blank. Are there supposed to be settings here and, if so, is there a way I can repair my preferences so this tab will show up again?

[image: Blank desktop tab]

My system is a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) running Mojave (10.14.2).

Comment: were you able to remove this issue?

Comment: A reboot seems to fix it.